# MVC 5 template not working with OAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook-oauth, asp.net-mvc-templates

When i try to login using fb/g+ in my mvc template app, it logs in successfully, but when i log off and re login, it again takes me to the external callback page instead of logging me into the app. Have tried a lot, but couldn't figure out. Any help is appreciated

Here are my ext login methods-

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
if (loginInfo == null)
{
     return RedirectToAction("Login");
}

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user    already has a login
        var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
        }
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }

            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = model.Email,
                Email = model.Email,
                DateOfRegistration = DateTime.Now,
                DisplayName = model.DisplayName
            };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Can we see a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Here are my ext login methods-

Comment: Is data being saved to AspNetUserLogins table?

Comment: Yes Data is being saved to AspNetUserLogins Table. And When i deleted all data from that table, everything worked fine. Thanks. I would have never thought of deleting data from that table hadn't you asked about it.

Comment: NO. The problem has again returned and this time its not going even on deleting that table's data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just deleted data from AspNetUserLogins and everything works fine now.